# Extract strings by delimiter 'space'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string of format `'32109 NV Santa Clara'`
I need to extract `'32109'` and `'Santa Clara'` in 2 different variables

eg strings:

```
'34123 NV Blue Earth'

'45167 MN San Jose'
```

Comment: Is it always the first word and two last words you need or does it vary?

Comment: the most simple one ... e.g. `const [postalCode, city] = '32109 NV Santa Clara'.split(/\s+[A-Z]{2}\s+/);` ... the regex splits the string at [the 2 uppercase asci letters wich is the US postal code (abbreviation) for any federal state and territory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._state_and_territory_abbreviations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [string.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to extract all the strings.

```js
const address = "32109 NV Santa Clara";

const [match, postalCode, state, city] = address.match(/(\d+) (\w+) (.*)/);

console.log(postalCode);
console.log(state);
console.log(city);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.split()` like below (all three string example)

```js
var strng = '34123 NV Blue Earth';
var arr = strng.split(/\s*[A-Z]{2}\s*/);
console.log(arr);


var strng1 = '45167 MN San Jose';
var arr1 = strng1.split(/\s*[A-Z]{2}\s*/);
console.log(arr1);


var strng2 = '32109 NV Santa Clara';
var arr2 = strng2.split(/\s*[A-Z]{2}\s*/);
console.log(arr2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code,

```
const s = '34123 NV Blue Earth';
const a = s.split(' ');
const [x, y] = [a[0], a.slice(2).join(' ')];
```

You can read more about [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to extract those data. What is a demiliter? A space?

```
const mystring = "45167 MN San Jose";
mystring.split(' ');
// ["45167", "MN", "San", "Jose"]
```

Reference to [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

You could also use regex to split by first whitespace:

```
mystring.split(/(?<=^\S+)\s/)
//  ["45167", "MN San Jose"]
```